# How to write unit testing for alert service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am new to writing unit test cases. I'm trying to write test cases for my alert service. I am using angular 7. My alert service and my alert model code like below.

My alert.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Alert, AlertType } from '../models/alert.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlertService {
  private subject = new Subject<Alert>();

  constructor() {}

  onAlert(): Observable<Alert> {
    return this.subject
      .asObservable();
  }

  success(message: string) {
    this.alert(new Alert(message, AlertType.Success));
  }

  error(message: string) {
    this.alert(new Alert(message, AlertType.Error));
  }

  info(message: string) {
    this.alert(new Alert(message, AlertType.Info));
  }

  warn(message: string) {
    this.alert(new Alert(message, AlertType.Warning));
  }

  alert(alert: Alert) {
    this.subject.next(alert);
  }

  clear() {
    this.subject.next(null);
  }
}
```

My alert.model.ts

```
export class Alert {
  constructor(public message: string, public type: AlertType) {}
}

export enum AlertType {
  Success,
  Error,
  Info,
  Warning
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your spec file.

add

```
export class FakeSubject {
  next(value: any) {}
  asObservable() {}
}
```

configure your testbed:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [{ provide: Subject, useClass: FakeSubject }],
}),
```

add a service getter before each test.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = TestBed.get(AlertService);
  });
```

add test, you can use this example for another test.

```
  it('success alert ', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'alert');
    const message = 'hi!';
    service.success(message);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Alert(message, AlertType.Success));
  });
```

and your utility methods:

```
  it('alert ', () => {
    subject = service['subject'];
    const spy = spyOn(subject, 'next');
    const alert = new Alert('hi', AlertType.Success);
    service.alert(alert);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(alert);
  });

  it('clear ', () => {
    subject = service['subject'];
    const spy = spyOn(subject, 'next');

    service.clear();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel your awesome. Its working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your welcome Ramesh. The best way to say thanks in stackOverflow is accept the answer as useful / best answer to help others with the same problem.!

Comment: Hi Manuel Panizzo, Can you please one more help me i need test cases for alert.component also can you please help me on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986033/how-to-write-unit-testing-for-alert-component
this is for alert component